# Swift 3, Xcode 8, Latest Firebase, setvalue crash app in release mode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app connects to firebase to read and update the database, it can run ok in debug mode.When I submit it to iTunes connect and use test flight to test, it crashes.

First, I passed an NSDictionary object to set value, crash.

Then I decided to setvalue one by one like this:

```
userRef.child(userId).child("email").setValue(user.email) //String
userRef.child(userId).child("name").setValue(user.name) //String
userRef.child(userId).child("imageUrl").setValue(user.imageUrl) //String
```

it crashed too in line `setValue(user.name)`.

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: Add three items to your question  1) print(userId)  and 2) print(user) and 3) The error message and include that data, along with a snippet of your Firebase structure *in your question*. As it is we don't have enough data to know what the issue is.